# socket recv in thread , wrong behavior

Tags: c, sockets, thread-safety, recv

Greeting !!

I use unpv13e library in linux developed as socket server , and listen a port which
will accept 3 socket clients (at most) , each client would has its own thread ....

While these 3 clients send very very quick , the recv function of socket server will
 receive said half of string came from client1 , half of another came from client2 , 
it is odd because I think these 3 socket clients would be run in different thread ,
also different socket id ,  so I am curious why it happened ?  let me explain in 
the following codes :

```
listenfd = Tcp_listen(ipaddr,portno,&addrlen);
cliaddr = Malloc(addrlen);
Signal(SIGINT, sig_int);
for ( ; ; ) {
    clilen = addrlen;
    connfd = Accept(listenfd, cliaddr, &clilen);
    err_msg("id [%05d] conned from %s",connfd,Sock_ntop(cliaddr, clilen));
    Pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &doit, (void *) connfd);
}


void * doit(void *arg)
{
    void web_child(int);
    Pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    web_child((int) arg);
    Close((int) arg);
    printf("thread [%05d] dead...\n",(int) arg);
    return(NULL);
}


void web_child(int sockfd)
{
    int        connfd;
    ssize_t    nread;
    char       line[1024];

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        line[0]=0x00 ;
        if ( (nread = Readline(sockfd, line, 1024)) == 0)
            break;         /* connection closed by other end */
        line[nread-2]=0x00 ;
        if(strncmp(line,"101",3)==0)
            Do101(line) ;
        if(strncmp(line,"201",3)==0)
            Do201(line) ;
        if(strncmp(line,"301",3)==0)
            Do301(line) ;
    }
}
```

Readline function in unpv13e library call recv , and check one char at a time 
until it is a '\n' and return , the nread usually 315 bytes or so ,
and I do not have send in this socket server !!
In my opinion , web_child function is run as thread , with different socketfd ,
and line is local var , so it is no way that 3 different client will effect each other,
socket client1 will always send string start with "101" , and client2 always send "201",
client3 send "301" ....

But somestimes I'll see a string in Do101(line) , which the firat half of it is "101" ,
and  second half of it came from client2 , they just effect each other ...
if these 3 clients send very very frequently , it might happened ... not very often ,
but it just happened !!

What kind of bug I've in the code ?  recv from different socketid in different thread 
will effect each other ?

Any suggestion are welcome !!  Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the library you're using?  https://github.com/k84d/unpv13e/

The readline functions don't appear to be threadsafe.  They use a static buffer and nothing to guard against concurrent access.

Comment: YES... it is the library I use !! in readline.c I saw lots of static in global there .... I read "UNIX network programming" book,  and found this library , there are several readline function  version , I think I use a version of not thread-safe ...... Can I said that if it is static there , they must be not  thread-safe ... Am I correct ?

Comment: This one https://github.com/k84d/unpv13e/blob/master/server/readline.c looks ok to me.

Comment: @alk - interesting, there's multiple versions in there.  I found https://github.com/k84d/unpv13e/blob/master/lib/readline.c

Answer (score 2):

If `Readline()` receives only 1 byte, this line fails:

```
line[nread-2]=0x00 ;
```

You might try changing it into:

```
line[nread-1]=0x00 ;
```

Comment: because I add ox0d,0x0a,0x00 in the sending string !!see :         ilen = strlen(strsql) ; strsql[ilen]=0x0d; strsql[ilen+1]=0x0a; strsql[ilen+2]=0x00; if (send(iConn,strsql,strlen(strsql),MSG_NOSIGNAL)<0){ printf("send to port 4600 error...\n"); exit(0) ; }